# Filter of Lebesgue measure one sets

Tags: measure-theory, filters

I am reading lecture notes I borrowed from friend. It defines the filter of subsets of $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure $1$. Then it defines sets $A$ to be called $F$-stationary iff $A \cap Y \neq \varnothing$ for all $Y$ in the filter. Then it writes the $F$-stationary sets are the sets of positive outer measure.

Why is it outer measure and not Lebesgue measure? And why is it true? Does it hold  that all subsets of $[0,1]$ with cardinality equal the cardinality of $[0,1]$ must have positive (outer or Lebesgue) measure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First the easy part, the Cantor set is of the same cardinality as $[0,1]$ and has Lebesgue measure zero.

Now, we want to define a notion of stationarity on *all* subsets, not just measurable sets. Sets which are not Lebesgue measurable cannot have outer measure zero (because the Lebesgue measure is complete).

Finally, suppose $E$ is any subset, and $A$ is measurable with measure $1$, such that $m^*(E\cap A)=0$ then $m^*(E)=m^*(E\setminus A)\leq m^*([0,1]\setminus A)=0$.

Comment: Beat me to it...

Comment: I can't find a funny comeback. I'm going to cook lunch, and I'll get back to you with a funny remark if I come up with one.

Comment: Why can a set that is not Lebesgue measurable not have outer measure zero?

Comment: @user58975: Having outer measure zero means that you're a subset of a measure zero Borel set. But the Lebesgue measure is defined as adding all the subsets of measure zero Borel sets. It follows that outer measure zero implies measurability, and therefore measure zero.

Comment: I am sorry: why does outer measure zero imply is subset of measure zero Borel set?

Comment: @user58975: What is your definition of the outer measure?

Comment: This: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Formal_definitions

Comment: @user58975: This is the definition of **an** outer measure. Not **the** Lebesgue outer measure. What differentiate the Lebesgue outer measure than any other outer measure that you can define on $2^{[0,1]}$?

Comment: @user58975: You can see that if $A$ has outer measure zero then every subset of $A$ has outer measure zero, by subadditivity it follows that $A$ has to be measurable with measure zero.

Comment: How does subadditivity imply $A$ is Lebesgue measurable of Lebesgue measure zero?

Comment: @user58975: $A$ is measurable if for every $E$ it holds that $m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\setminus E)$. Because $m^*(A)=0$ and both $A\cap E$ and $A\setminus E$ are subsets of $A$, both have measure zero. Because subadditivity we have $$0=m^*(A)=m^*((A\cap E)\cup(A\setminus E))\leq m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\setminus E)=0+0=0.$$

Comment: @AsafKaragila We must show if set $A$ has outer measure $m^\ast$ zero then $A$ must be Lebesgue measurable. I don't understand how what you wrote shows that. Could you please say more? I am sorry.

Comment: @user58975: It seems that you will benefit greatly from asking a separate question.